# Embedding from PyTorch segmentation model

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation, torchvision

I'm trying to get mean embedding from finetuned `torchvision.models.segmentation.fcn_resnet50` model.
One approach that I've tested is to swap classifier with `nn.Identity` layer (returns tensor of shape [batch_size, feature_num, h, w]) and use `torch.mean` on inference

```py
model_embedder.classifier = Identity()
outputs = torch.mean(model_embedder(inputs), dim=[2, 3])
```

But I've noticed that [`forward()`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/segmentation/_utils.py) method of Torchvision segmentation models is like:

```py
# ...
x = features["out"]
x = self.classifier(x)
x = F.interpolate(x, size=input_shape, mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
result["out"] = x
# ...
```

And use of `F.interpolate()` on features may lead to unexpected results (memory leakage and segmentation fault specifically). I've also tried to add `AvgPooling` layer to model directly

```py
class EmbeddingAvgPooling(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EmbeddingAvgPooling, self).__init__()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.mean(x, dim=[2, 3])
  
model_embedder.classifier = EmbeddingAvgPooling()
```

But of course, it's not connected with `F.interpolate()` application problem in any way. (In this setup the error is not segmentation fault but rather `size mismatch` from `F.interpolate()`, which is expectable). What can I do to fix this problem? Do I need to overwrite `forward()` method of the model (how?) or maybe other variants are possible?

P.S. I understand that the use of the segmentation model as an embedder might be not the greatest idea, but currently trying to test specifically this approach.

Comment: You can literally do `model.forward = new_forward`

Comment: You want to change [this line](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/segmentation/_utils.py#L24) into `torch.mean(x, dim=[2, 3])`. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Natthaphon Hongcharoen classifier is also not needed (need to mean features)
Got you point with forward, thanks. What do you think: is this variant (rewriting/coping and overloading forward from scratch) is optimal?

Comment: Personally I prefer creating a new object and do `forward` there using the variables from these layers. It sometime a real pain to edit the existing object.

Comment: Wait, you just want to mean the `feature`?

Comment: Have you try `torch.mean(model.backbone(x))`?

Comment: So `model.backbone(x)` will return a `dict`. It should be `torch.mean(model.backbone(x)['out'])`

Comment: Sounds reasonable!
I'll try approach with `model.backbone(x)`